# Passing argument to enum abstract method

Tags: java, oop, enums, factory

I need to give a Factory of search properties (as part of the Strategy OOP principle).
I've written the following enum for the choices:

```
    public enum CompareChoice {
    ABS {
        public Path compare(Path path1, Path path2) {
            return absCompare(path1, path2);
        }
    },

    TYPE {
        public Path compare(Path path1, Path path2) {
            String type1 = getFileType(path1);
            String type2 = getFileType(path2);
            int compareValue = type1.compareTo(type2);
            if (compareValue == 0) {
                return absCompare(path1, path2);
            }

            if (compareValue > 0) {
                return path1;
            }

            return path2;
        }

    },

    SIZE {
        public Path compare(Path path1, Path path2) throws IOException {
            Long size1 = Files.size(path1);
            Long size2 = Files.size(path2);
            int compareValue = size1.compareTo(size2);
            if (compareValue == 0) {
                return absCompare(path1, path2);
            }

            if (compareValue > 0) {
                return path1;
            }

            return path2;
        }
    };

    public abstract Path compare(Path path1, Path path2) throws IOException;
}
```

The problem I face is that I need to support reverse sorting (of all three choices).
I thought of passing a `boolean` argument somehow to these implementations of `compare` but I have no idea how.
Any ideas of how to implement this well by still using an `enum` would be very helpful!

Comment: What version of Java do you have? Newer than 8?

Comment: Only 8 (not allowed to use a newer version for this exercise)

Comment: That's OK, 8 is enough.

Comment: How is `compare` method used? How are you intending to pass the boolean?

Comment: The compare method is used in a custom sort that I implemented. I don't know how to pass a boolean, this is my question.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your question, but why can't you just add a third, boolean parameter to your `compare()` method, as in: `public Path compare(Path, Path, boolean)` ?

Comment: Becuase it means that everytime I use this compare method in the in the "sort" I will have to pass the same boolean over and over.. doesn't look elegant to me.. is that acceptable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Java 8, `java.util.Comparator<T>` has a default method [`reversed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed()) that you can use.

You can make your `enum` implement `Comparator`, then you get reverse sort "for free", but that means changing signature of `compare` to fit the `Comparator` contract (you'll need to think of another name for the method, in my example I'll name it `select`;

Taking just one of your enum values to keep it short:

```
public enum CompareChoice implements Comparator<Path> {

  SIZE {
    @Override
    public int compare(Path path1, Path path2) {
      int r = Long.compare(
        Files.size(path1),
        Files.size(path2)
      );
      if (r == 0) {
        return absCompare(path1, path2);
      }
      else {
        return r;
      }
    }
  };

  // rest of the methods:
  public static Path select(Comparator<? super Path> rule, Path path1, Path path2) {
    return rule.compare(path1, path2) <= 0 ? path1 : path2;
  }
}
```

So then, when you use the class instance:

```
CompareChoice choice = CompareChoice.SIZE;

Path path1 = fileOfSize(1, TB);
Path path2 = fileOfSize(3, TB);

Path naturalOrderResult = CompareChoice.select(choice, path1, path2);
Path reversedOrderResult = CompareChoice.select(choice.reversed(), path1, path2);

assert path1 == naturalOrderResult;
assert path2 == reversedOrderResult;
```

You can look at other default methods in comparator to check out other stuff you also get from implementing `Comparator<T>`, though most of it might be of not much use to you.

You might also consider refactoring it as a whole, so your `CompareChoice` might not be a "true" comparator, but instead returns a comparator. That way you get better separation of concerns with comparator implementation:

```
public enum CompareChoice {
  ABS {
    public Comparator<? extends Path> comparator() {
      return Comparator.comparing(this::absCompare); // whatever absCompare means
    }
  },

  SIZE {
    public Comparator<? extends Path> comparator() {
      return Comparator.comparingLong(Files::size).thenComparing(ABS.comparator());
    }
  };


  public abstract Comparator<? extends Path> comparator();
}
```

Comment: Note: my solution requires not only changing return type for `compare` method, but also calling `reversed()` on `CompareChoice` doesn't produce a `CompareChoice` instance, so such calls can't be chained. All in all, I like approach with `comparator()` method a lot more here.